# merge: start - not something we can merge

Tags: git

My repo has a branch the name is 'start' and my git is connected with the repo well when I checked 'git remote -v', but for merging from 'start' to 'main',  it has an error 'merge: start - not something we can merge'. How can I solve this?

I searched about this, the solution was to checkout from the branch but when I do like that, it also has an error 'error: pathspec 'start' did not match any file(s) known to git'.

Comment: Shows the command and the output ion the question, please.

Comment: 1. git branch >>> * main.  2. git fetch start >>> fatal: 'start' does not appear to be a git repository, fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 3. git checkout origin >>> error: pathspec 'origin' did not match any file(s) known to git.  4.  git merge start. >>>merge: start - not something we can merge.  5. git checkout start. >>>. error: pathspec 'start' did not match any file(s) known to git.  @eftshift0

Comment: ... in the question.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the code properly formatted.

Comment: @Uranus_ly You don't seem to know the difference between a branch and a remote. You don't even seem to know what an repo is. As a result, everything you're saying to Git is wrong. I suggest learning about Git before using it. You're going to break something if you keep thrashing like this.

Answer (score 2):

> My repo has a branch the name is 'start'

No it doesn't.

Perhaps the *remote* repo has a branch called `start`. If you'd like to obtain it and merge it into your `main`, say

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/start
```

(But that won't work if the remote repo doesn't have a `start` branch either.)